# If $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i+\omega^k} =2\omega^{2k}$ for $k=1,2$, find $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i+1}$.

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, rational-functions, roots-of-unity, meromorphic-functions

> In this question, $\omega$ is the complex cube root of $1$ and $a_i \in \mathbb R$.   If $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + \omega} =2\omega ^2$$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + \omega ^2} =2\omega\,,$$
> then find $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + 1}\,.$$

I think I have solved it correctly (answer is $2$) , but please check my proof.

**Proof**:

Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $$f(x)=\left (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + x}\right) -2x^2 $$

As per the given condition, $\omega$ and $\omega ^2$ are the roots of the equation $f(x)=0$.

Now, if we have some equation whose roots are $\alpha , \beta$ (for example) then by using the transformation $x \to x^{1/3}$, we get the equation whose roots are $\alpha ^3, \beta ^3$.

Using that here, $f(x^{1/3})=0$ should have the roots $\omega ^3, \omega ^6 $ that is,

$1$ is a root of $f(x^{1/3})=0$

$\implies f(1)=0$

$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i + 1}=2$$

Which is the right answer, by the way.

**My question:**

Is this proof using transformations correct or not?

Comment: I'd just set $\omega = 1$ in one of the two given equalities.

Comment: @Rigel  That is not allowed: $\omega$ is a fixed constant.  Just like you cannot replace $2$ by $1$ in the following equality $2+2=4$.

Comment: I see. I haven't read the second line. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Aditya  While I think the answer is indeed $2$ as you said, your solution is very sketchy.  I am quite certain that the method you used is not correct.

Comment: @Batominovski , could you point the mistake out? I thought of using transformations because $\omega ^3 =\omega ^6=1$ .

Comment: @Aditya  I will take a look again later.  I have to be out in a few minutes.

Comment: Transformation $x \to x^{1/3}$ is a [multi-valued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), I suspect you assumed the [principal branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) of it. Thus the suspicion raised by Batominovski.

Comment: Another remark, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+\omega}=2\omega^2$ and 
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i +\omega^2}=2\omega$ are equivalent, since $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ are [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

$$2\omega^2=\overline{2\omega}=
\overline{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+\omega^2}}=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \overline{\left(\frac{1}{a_i+\omega^2}\right)}=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\overline{1}}{\overline{a_i+\omega^2}}=\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+\overline{\omega^2}}=
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i+\omega}$$

Comment: Oh, there you go, found [something related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864323/how-to-prove-the-below-statement).

Comment: @Aditya: If you consider the equation $g(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ and apply the same argument as you have applied, wouldn't you get that $g(1) = 0$? (But that is not true.) Your argument (if I see it correctly) seems to imply that every equation with $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ as roots also has $1$ as a root.

Comment: @Aryaman Maithani, I see your point. I get that my argument is flawed, but why? I can't figure out what exactly is gone wrong there. Could you help me figure that out?

Comment: @Aditya: the error is mainly what was mentioned earlier but I have elaborated on that in a comment now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out, in the comments is that the "transformation" $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is multivalued and you're misusing that.

Let us see this better.
When you wish to make the substitution $x \mapsto x^{\color{red}{1/3}}$, you should make a choice of which cube root you are choosing for each $x$.

Suppose you have made the choice to choose $\omega$ for $x = 1$. This means that you must fix $1^{\color{red}{1/3}} = \omega$ in your later substitutions.

This is the error that you made. Using the fact that $\omega$ is a root, you concluded that $1$ is a root of $f(x^{\color{red}{1/3}})$ but then you must remember that $1^{\color{red}{1/3}}$ is $\omega$.

In particular, you *cannot* write
$$f(1^{\color{red}{1/3}}) = f(1) = 0$$
since $1^{\color{red}{1/3}} = \omega$ and not $1$.

---

Similarly, if you considered $x \mapsto x^{\color{blue}{1/3}}$ and chose $\omega^2$ for $1^{\color{blue}{1/3}}$, you'd run into the same problem.

---

I already gave an example in the comments of how you could use this to derive that $1$ is a root of $x^2 + x + 1$ even though it's not.
Another example of such a thing is misuse of the square root.

For example, you could consider $g(x) = x+1$, note that $-1$ is a root and then using the transformation $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ incorrectly, conclude that $1$ is also a root.

(In fact, this is the spirit behind many "proofs" of $-1=1$.)